# Member plugin - register approval, restrict downloads, members only pages

Tags: members

I've seen a few members plugins but was wondering if any of them can do a few things i need.

1) I need two different types of users. One is a standard user another is a Partner. The standard user needs to be able to register without any approval, but the Partners need to have the account approved to ensure they are actually a partner.

2) I have file upload fields on one of my custom post types. I need to only allow registered users to view the files. When someone who isn't logged in clicks on one of the files they get taken to the registration/login page, then when they login they get taken back to the page they were on.

3) Members only pages. There needs to be some pages that only user that are logged in can see and view. So the page isn't even visible in the menu unless the user is logged in. These pages will contain downloads as well for members only. There will be a couple of different sections for members only. Some only for Partners the rest for all members.

Is there any plugin that can do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would be the [Role Scoper](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/role-scoper/) plugin, possibly used in conjunction with [Theme My Login](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/theme-my-login/).

These two in combination are quite powerful and can greatly add to the CMS aspect of wordpress.

Comment: I've tried using Role Scoper before and just tried again, I find it very confusing to use and really don't understand how i'm supposed to use it.

Comment: @Corbula Well, there's also the [Members](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) plugin, which is a bit more light-weight but also less powerful. You could give that a run.

Comment: I've managed to partially get this done, using Members and Cimy Extra User Fields for the registration form. I've not got 2) working and i'm still working on 1).